# Finding Distributional Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

In the range $0 \leq r < \infty$, find the solution of the equation $$\frac{d^{2}u}{dr^{2}} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{du}{dr} - \frac{n(n+1)}{r^{2}} u = a \delta(r-R),$$ where $n$ is an integer and $0<R<\infty$ is a constant, which is regular at $r=0$ and at infinity and vanishes for $a=0$.

I started by finding the homogeneous solution $u_{h} = r^{n}, r^{-n-1}$ (by plugging in the ansatz $u_{h} = r^{\alpha}$). How to proceed from here?

Comment: It is not quite clear whether $R$ is a constant or a function of $r$ and $A$.

Comment: $R$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d^{2}u}{dr^{2}} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{du}{dr} - \frac{n(n+1)}{r^{2}} u = a \delta(r-R)$$
Let $u(r)=r^n f(r)$ then $u'=n r^{n-1}f +r^n f'$ and $u''=n(n-1)r^{n-2}f+2n r^{n-1}f'+r^n f''$
$$ n(n-1)r^{n-2}f+2n r^{n-1}f'+r^n f''+ 2(n r^{n-2}f +r^{n-1} f') - n(n+1)r^{n-2} f = a \delta(r-R)$$
$$r^n f''+2(n+1) r^{n-1}f' = a \delta(r-R)$$
$$\frac{d}{dr}(r^{2(n+1)}f')=r^{2(n+1)}f''+2(n+1) r^{2n+1}f'= a \delta(r-R)r^{n+2} $$
Supposing that $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function :
$$r^{2(n+1)}f'=a\int  \delta(r-R)r^{n+2}dr = a R^{n+2}H(r-R)+constant$$
H is the Heaviside step function.
We are looking for only one particular solution. Then, no need for any constant.
$$f'=a R^{n+2}r^{-2(n+1)}H(r-R)$$
$$f=a R^{n+2}\int r^{-2(n+1)}H(r-R)dr=a R^{n+2}\frac{r^{-2n-1}-R^{-2n-1}}{-2n-1}H(r-R)$$
A particular solution is $r^nf(r)$
$$u(r)=c_1 r^n+c_2 r^{-n-1}+a R^{n+2}r^n\frac{r^{-2n-1}-R^{-2n-1}}{-2n-1}H(r-R)$$
$$u(r)=c_1 r^n+c_2 r^{-n-1}+a R\frac{(\frac{r}{R})^n-(\frac{r}{R})^{-n-1}}{2n+1}H(r-R)$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there a mistake in "$$a\int  \delta(r-R)r^{n+2}dr = a r^{n+2}H(r-R)+constant?"$$

Comment: Hi nchar! You are right, there is a mistake in the formula. This changes completely the end of the calculus. Sorry for that and even more sorry because I have not enough time this evening to reconsider the next equations. Now, I only have the time to suppress them in my answer above.

Comment: The preceeding answer has been corrected. Many thanks to nchar for pointed the mistake out.

Comment: Why can we assume that $u=r^nf$? Wouldn't we lose something in zero?

Comment: With this method, we are not trying to find the general solution of the ODE. We are searching for only ONE particular solution. So, it doesn't matter to loose one or many solutions. It is important to understand that the general solution will be finally obtain by adding a particular solution to the general solution of the associated homogeneous ODE. Then no solution will be lost at the final step.

Comment: In fact, in the present case, we use a particular solution of the homogeneous ODE i.e. : $c r^n$ and we remplace the coefficient $c$ by an unknown function to be found i.e. : $f(r) r^n $. This is the well-known "variation of parameters" method http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VariationofParameters.html